# Error 1 when restoring iPad

Tags: ipad, restore

I bought an used iPad 2 recently. It worked okay, but then I got a small error message and my iPad started to reboot itself every 2 minutes, I decided to restore the iPad via iTunes. When I restored the iPad, I got error (-1) message at the end of restore and the restore doesn't appear to have actually happened. I'm not sure if it is dead or just in recovery mode.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is there anything we can do to arrive at a "solved" answer for you? Specifically, this article can help you point to the exact place where you are failing in most cases. http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mere a hardware problem, if anyone gets this error, don't hesitate, take your iDevice to the service or warranty center.. luckily Apple devices have so called world warranty so even if you bought it used and it's still on warranty, take it to the proper place to get a new iPad.. it will take 2-3 weeks. Hopefully you won't ever see -1 error message

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried more that 1 computer and have tried entering the iPad into DFU mode, take the iPad to an authorized repair center as it may be defective.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4097

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3714819?start=0&tstart=0